# How do I remove 3M adhesive from any solid surface?

Tags: adhesive

I stuck a utility hook with 3M adhesive, removed it, but the adhesive residue is left behind.

Answer (score 3):

A **hair dryer** or **vegetable oil**, left on the sticky surface for a few minutes, possibly repeated. Oil also takes off glue from used glass jar label residue.

Comment: I left a hair dryer on my sticky surface on the wall for 5minutes and now its stuck to the wall ;)



only kidding, I like the hair dryer idea for a couple of areas around the home my end.

Comment: When you write "vegetable oil", please write which type has worked for you. Some oils are vastly different from each other. Coconut oil in particular is similar to mineral oil.

Answer (score 1):

I think WD-40 can get the job done. Just check that you can properly clean it out after (maybe spray on some part of the solid surface that is not very visible).

Comment: The Problem with Petrol (which is the essential Part of WD40) and other Oils is, that it can leave Stains, if the Surface is porous enough.

Comment: Oho ok thanks, it's indeed useful to spray on less visible areas...

Answer (score 1):

**This technique uses no solvents** - and a high success rate.

If the surface with the adhesive is firm, I've had good luck using another adhesive with the same tack or slightly more tacky.

Wind a bit of tape (say) around your finger with the adhesive facing outward. Press your taped finger on the stick area and "pull" the adhesive free from the surface.

If the surface is latex paint, you risk the possibility of pulling the layer of paint off the wall so work in a small area from the centre outward. Chances are that if the hook didn't remove the paint your taped finger won't either.

I find this does much less damage than liquid solvents and there's no clean-up afterward.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to use White Spirit. It generally dissolves these kinds of adhesives. Use kitchen paper with a small quantity of White Spirit and gently rub it away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cotton dipped in petrol to remove the sticky adhesive.

Comment: Deisel fuel, kerosene, or gasoline? Please be cautious of localization as not everyone refers to `fuel` as `petrol`

Comment: @Phlume That's a legitimate concern, but I bet all of the above would work similarly. Naphtha, heavy naphtha and aromatics, naphtha and light aromatics.

Answer (score 0):

1. Isopropyl alcohol 99.9% (works for most surfaces & is not to aggressive)
2. Silicone remover
3. There are also special removers for such jobs on the market, but in my view, with 1. & 2. you can clean other stuff also with, not only limited to adhesives like 3M...

Get a bottle of Isopropyl would be best (and if you dilute it with destillatt-water you can use it for sore desinfection also, search in the net if you like...)
Also there is a little trick if you do the removing: you should turn the lobe  after each or second wipe, so it goes 2-times faster.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that the 3M company will have an exact recommendation for removing any of their products most effectively. It's not a mom 'n pop shop — they have access to massive resources for just such a question.

I'd call the 3M toll-free hot line 1 (800) 364-3577 or at GetHUMAN 1 (651) 733-1110

Answer (score 0):

Orange essential oil is my go-to! Just a good rub with a bit of it works on most adhesives.  It's never failed me once and it smells good too.